# Algorithm for specific load balancing/arbitration problem

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatory-logic

I'm trying to design an algorithm for some specific arbitration requirements and I have a feeling I'm on well-trodden ground, but lack the maths background to properly analyse it. If someone could point me in the direction of further reading or prior work (or, of course, develop a complete answer should you wish) that would be immensely helpful.

### The problem

Find an output which satisfies the conditions below for a given input. Previous inputs and outputs need not be considered. (I've specified this for simplicity.) The idea is to preserve the input grouping while maximising the output occupancy and prioriting higher values over lower values. The exact requirements are set in stone, cannot be changed, and are described below.

Input: `N` lists of zero to `M` positive integers.

Output: a selection of between 1 and `k` of the input data accompanied by their position in the nested lists, identified by `(x,y)`, `x` ∈ `[0,M-1]`, `y` ∈ `[0,N-1]`, with `y` indexing the list of lists and `x` indexing the individual list.

The whole, flat set of valid input integers can be identified by their indices `(x,y) ∈ U`, with `|U| = N ✕ M`.

Constraints:

- let `S` be the set of `(x,y)`'s output simultaneously.

1. maximise `|S|`, up to `k` (which may be less than `N ✕ M`)
2. among the solutions that maximise `|S|` (discounting those that do not), minimise the number of distinct `y`'s in `S` (i.e. minimise the number of different input lists represented in the output) as far as possible while satisfying (1).

- let `f` be an arbitrary function from `(x,y)` to the strictly positive integers (i.e. the integers described in the input section).
- for each `(x,y)`, let `(x,y)` belong to a class `T(y')`, `(x,y) ∈ T(y') iff y = y' and (x,y) ∈ U`.

3. `∀j ∀(x,y) ∈ (S ∩ T(j)), f((x,y)) >= f((x',y')) ∀(x',y') ∈ (T(j) ∩ (U - S))`. In other words, all list elements output must have a greater integer than those from the same list that are left behind.
4. (and here's the problem) Each input list from which at least one integer (and `x,y`) is output can be described as a "selected list." A list from which no element is output is a "deselected list." The integers inside the input lists affect which lists are "selected" in the following way. Among the list combinations that could be selected without violating the need to maximise the number of outputs and to minimise the number of *selected lists*, the algorithm must choose a combination which selects higher integers in favour of lower ones. Specifically, allow the lists to be ordered by their highest integer. Where a choice exists subject to requirements 1 and 2, choose lists that are higher in this ordering over ones which are lower. (Note that as a consequence of 3, the greatest element of a selected list will always be output.)

   Proposed formalism to follow tomorrow.

So as you can see, requirement 4 (choose lists with higher max numbers) affects which *lists* get chosen. A greedy approach, either with respect to list length, or with respect to the integer value, does not yield a correct result, since many lists (of potentially differing lengths) could be used to fill the `k` slots; choosing natural numbers first and then choosing lists based on those fails to minimise the number of input lists selected from.

Comment: @D.W. **(A)** in requirement 2 I said "as far as possible." I.e out of all the solutions that maximise `|S|`, choose those that produce the smallest number of distinct `y`s. **(B)** A list is "not output" if no `(x,y)` (`y`=that list number) from that list is chosen to be output. I will re-write the "Let L..." sentence (I agree it wasn't very clear) but I meant "let L be all of the elements that are being output that belong to a particular input list" and "let L' be all of the other elements in that list, that are not output." **(C)** Yes exactly, there's a single output and a single input.

Comment: @D.W. I really appreciate the feedback which exposed some woolly thinking in the question. I've added an informal explanation of req nọ 4 but will add a formal description later.

Comment: If I give you a candidate solution, can you efficiently verify whether it meets all your conditions?  It looks like requirement 4 is non-trivial to check.  But am I missing an easy way to verify it?  I'm more interested in requirements that are in terms of a candidate solution rather than in terms of what process was used to choose it (as I might have in mind a different process than what you were anticipating).

Comment: It's also not clear to me what requirement 4 means.  If one solution involves picking a list with number 100 and a list with number 1, and another solution involves picking a list with number 51 and a list with number 49, I'm not sure how to tell (from what is written in the post) which solution you prefer.